# I cant install pyside

Tags: python, pyside

My problem

[image]

I installed pyside on python version 3.4 but I needed to change to a newer version I changed to 3.6 and it gave me the same error and now I am working on version 3.9 all are 32 bit.

Comment: PySide is deprecated, better use PySide2 or PySide6

Comment: Please always post code or debug output as ***text***, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed the PIP installation as you did, but I succeeded by downloading the PySide WHL package

You can search for PySide [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/), see which versions are currently supported, and install via PIP install XX.whl

Comment: Those packages are all old versions of pyside for qt4 (which is obsolete and no longer supported).

Comment: Thanks for helping